# Ubuntu 22.04 /var/lib/locales/supported.d

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, ubuntu-22.04

I am attempting to upgrade an old Ubuntu 14 Docker image to 22.04. One of the commands in the Dockerfile is `ln -s /usr/share/i18n/SUPPORTED /var/lib/locales/supported.d/all`.

This is failing on Ubuntu 22.04 because the directory `/var/lib/locales` doesn't exist.

- I could just create the directory before running the command, but I am not sure this will actually have the desired effect.
- On Ubuntu 14 the file `/usr/share/i18n/SUPPORTED` exists as part of the base image... but on Ubuntu 22.04 I had to install the package `locales` to get that file to appear.
- Is there another package I need to install to get the directory `/var/lib/locales`? Again I could just create the directory, but if the convention has changed creating the directory won't have any effect, since the locale files will never get picked up.

For reference here is the entire command

```
ln -s /usr/share/i18n/SUPPORTED /var/lib/locales/supported.d/all
locale-gen
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only important  part of the three command lines you posted is probably the `export LANG=en_US.UTF-8` setting up the desired [language/locale](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Locale).

The previous two *appear* to be ***workarounds*** to ensure that en_US.UTF-8 is properly supported and available.

On a modern Ubuntu I'd start with the `locales` package that is supposed to be installed by default and then run  `locale -a` run to see what is supported out-of-the box and by default. For my Ubuntu 22 LTS that shows:

```
locale -a

C
C.utf8
POSIX
en_US.utf8
```

and then I'd migrate

```
ln -s /usr/share/i18n/SUPPORTED /var/lib/locales/supported.d/all
locale-gen
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

to a simple:

```
export LANG=en_US.utf8
```

If that proves to be insufficient for the application you're running, you might need to install the language-pack packages: `language-pack-en-base` and/or  `language-pack-en`.